# What software do I need to convert a DVD to common formats? And what are the recommended formats?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to rip a DVD (product instruction manual for my company) and convert the files into common formats for users to download and play on their computers.

I was planning on offering .MOV, .MP4, .WMV and .SWF (is this overkill?). I was able to use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert the files to .MP4, but I am not sure how to convert the rest.

I am looking for a software recommendation (Windows) that will cover all of the formats.

Comment: Should this be two questions?

Comment: I would also like to mention that, as I realize I can "Google it" there are so many results that look like spyware, I would rather a recommendation from the community.

Comment: Do you really want to distribute videos to your customers? Would it be possible to upload the videos to youtube instead? That way, the videos can help your existing customers as well as people considering your product. And it costs you nothing.

Comment: @ObscureRobot Unfortunately many of our customers work at corporations that block Youtube network wide, so we need to either self host videos, send physical copies or allow downloads. The download option is  a huge cost saver.

Comment: S3 is a very easy way to host your videos, just turn on web server mode and you are pretty much done.

Comment: Drai, which OS do you use? PC? Mac? Linux?

Comment: @Globalnomad PC, I mentioned Windows in my question.

Comment: @ObscureRobot Thanks, we still need to offer a download.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [Xilisoft](http://www.xilisoft.net/video-converter-ultimate.html?gclid=CKux__vP4rACFQK5Kgod-R3W3Q) and it works well for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Mpeg streamclip, its free, and I believe you can open the DVD right into mpeg and then convert it to anything you would like, If you are unable to open the DVD, then transcode your mp4 from handbrake (another great tool) into any file you would like

Answer (score 0):

I've had great results in the past using [CloneDVD](http://www.clonedvd.net/) (currently $70) to rip DVD's to MP4.

As a professional editor, the thought of ripping a highly compressed DVD to another lossy format like MP4 gives me the willies; however, as WMV and SWF compressions will ultimately be further quite lossy, you probably won't lose enough quality to be significantly detrimental.